# How to use document.getElementById("elemId").innerHTML based on a value greater than 0?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

How to change the page HTML based on a variable value being greater than 0?

I believe that `document.getElementById("elemId").innerHTML` is the way to go but do not know how to add in the variable part.

I have been trying to find out how you can switch HTML in a page based on a value.  My skills are limited in this area. I'm good at searching for answers online but found nothing this time.

`##CUSTOMER_CREDITLIMIT#`  is a system generated code that returns a client credit amount.  So if they have credit show some HTML else show different HTML.  On the live page it will render 2000 for example.

```
 <div id="ecomp"> <!-- HTML rendered here --> </div>

<script>

var n = ##CUSTOMER_CREDITLIMIT#;
if ( n > 0) { 

document.getElementById("ecomp").innerHTML = '<h1>CREDIT CLIENT HTML</h1>'
} else { 
document.getElementById("ecomp").innerHTML = '<h1>CASH CLIENT HTML</h1>'

}

</script>
```

Comment: What is the question? I'm not quite sure what you need help with.

Comment: How to change the page HTML based on a variable value being greater than 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put your script block *after* the element.
Otherwise, the element won't exist when the script runs.

Comment: Thanks but made no difference?

Comment: How to change the page HTML based on a variable value being greater than 0